# How to eval javascript code with Ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

We have tested a custom ajax navigation, now we use Turbolinks but he does not support IE8 & 9. So now we want to use wiselinks who have a full browser compatibily.

But we struggle to execute the Javascript code between each page.

here the code :

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.role
//= require wiselinks
//= require_tree ../..
//= require_self

var startSpinner, stopSpinner;

startSpinner = function() {
  $('#loading-indicator').show();
};

stopSpinner = function() {
  $('#loading-indicator').fadeOut();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  window.wiselinks = new Wiselinks($('#PageContainer'));
  $(document).off('page:loading').on('page:loading', function(event, $target, render, url) {
    console.log("Loading: " + url + " to " + $target.selector + " within '" + render + "'");
    startSpinner();
  });
  $(document).off('page:redirected').on('page:redirected', function(event, $target, render, url) {
    return console.log("Redirected to: " + url);
  });
  $(document).off('page:always').on('page:always', function(event, xhr, settings) {
    console.log("Wiselinks page loading completed");
    stopSpinner();
  });
  $(document).off('page:done').on('page:done', function(event, $target, status, url, data) {
    console.log("Wiselinks status: '" + status + "'");
  });
  $(document).off('page:fail').on('page:fail', function(event, $target, status, url, error, code) {
    console.log("Wiselinks status: '" + status + "'");
  });
});
```

job.js :

```
$('@JRP').ready(function(){
    console.log('AVF');
    var $container = $("#component-view .list");
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.job',
        masonry: {
            gutterWidth: 0
        }
    });
    $container.toggleClass('grid').toggleClass('list').isotope( 'reLayout' ).isotope();
        // creates select dropdown

    $("#job-result-options-filter").click(function(e){

        $("#facetwrapper").slideToggle();
    });
    $("#job-result-options-filter").pageslide({ href: '#facets' });

    $('#toggle-sizes').click(function(){
        $container
                .toggleClass('grid')
                .toggleClass('list')
                .isotope('reLayout');
        return false;
    });

});
```

if i do a blank refresh of the page Job the JS is executed but if i come from the link with the ajax loading the JS is not executed and nothing in my error log.

How i can debug this ? or find a way to execute the JS when the job page is render ?

here the gem used : https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks

Comment: I don't understand what is `$('@JRP')`?

Comment: it's a jquery role selector i have <div role="JRP">

Comment: I wonder if that is valid to call `ready()` on an element. *The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.* http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: if i do this : $('@JRP').ready(function(event, $target, status, url, data) {

with a blank refresh the JS is loaded and evaluated but with the ajax call is not.
the creator of the gem tell me to use page:done, instead of ready

Comment: I know `page:done` as I used this gem before. I just said that usage on ready() is not legit according to doc. You then have two document ready event on same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is quite easy. The idea is not to call your custom codes on document ready. Instead, wrap all of them into a jQuery function, and then call this function at both document ready and page:done.

```
// You custom code
$.fn.my_app_init = function() {
 console.log('AVF');
 //...
 $('#toggle-sizes').click(function(){
 //...
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).my_app_init(); // Call this function
  window.wiselinks = new Wiselinks($('#PageContainer'));

  $(document).off('page:always').on('page:always', function(event, xhr, settings) {
    console.log("Wiselinks page loading completed");
    stopSpinner();
    $(document).my_app_init(); // Call this again on page change.
  });     
});
```